# can not create file by windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

in my windows service I Create file to log but now service can not run

```
Logger.InitLogFile("BridgeServiceLog.txt");
```

give me this error  **Error 1053: The Service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion**

```
public BridgeService()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Logger.InitLogFile("BridgeServiceLog.txt");
    Trace.WriteLine(Logger.logSwitch.TraceInfo, "Trace Started");

    this.ServiceName = "BridgeService";
    if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("BridgeSource"))
    {
         System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("BridgeSource", "BridgeLog");
    }
    _bridgeServiceEventLog.Source = "BridgeSource";
    _bridgeServiceEventLog.Log = "BridgeLog";
}
```

my onStart method

```
      protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
      {
            Trace.WriteLineIf(Logger.logSwitch.TraceInfo, "OnStart method Started");

            try
            {
                 _bridgeServiceEventLog.WriteEntry("new OnStart");
                 if (Vytru.Platform.Bridge.Configuration.LicenseValidetor.ValidCountAndTypeDevices())
                 {
                      SharedData.InitializeBridge();
                      // WsInitializeBridge();
                 }
                 else
                 {

                      this.Stop();
                      _bridgeServiceEventLog.WriteEntry("LicenseValidetor Error");
                 }
                 _bridgeServiceEventLog.WriteEntry("end Start");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                 Trace.WriteLineIf(Logger.logSwitch.TraceError, e.Message);
                 _bridgeServiceEventLog.WriteEntry("error In onstart method " + e.Message);
            }
            Trace.WriteLineIf(Logger.logSwitch.TraceInfo, "OnStart Ended");

      }
```

Comment: Why doesn't it run? Does it give an error? What is `SharedData.APPLICATION_LOCAL_PATH`?

Comment: can you post your `Start` function?

Comment: The error you report is too generic, you nave an unhandled exception in your on start.

Comment: The Event Viewer may give you more detail on the exception occurring.  Throwing out a swag, could be permissions to the log folder.

Comment: @tito11 I see your addition, is that one too generic: every failure in OnStart are reporter like  that unless you do some better exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

You should start a new thread in your `OnStart` function, otherwise the ServiceManager will think that the application was shutdown.. You can also get this message if the `OnStart` function exits to fast.

You can see the example provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart%28VS.80%29.aspx) for how to start a service